# Which is correct, on or upon?

Tags: questions

In the following example, would it be correct to replace both uses of 'upon'?

> Tom further encouraged Blain's team regarding the proposed trade deal, adding **that before everything would be agreed upon, nothing would be agreed upon.**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Per the usage deities](http://legalwritingeditor.com/2012/04/03/on-v-upon-does-it-really-matter/), *on* and *upon* are interchangeable, though *upon* lends a more formal, emphatic note.